# Common Lisp or Scheme for server-side?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, functional-programming

I wonder if some functional languages are used for web development and which are most useful and supported with that goal?

Comment: Neither Common Lisp nor Scheme are functional languages. Try one of the many Erlang/Haskell web frameworks.

Comment: @Vijay Mathew: The Lisps are functional. While they technically multi-paradigm, they definitely allow a programmer to be purely functional if he so wishes.

Comment: @Greg so does C. (think function pointers :-))

Comment: @Vijay Mathew: I suppose my counter in this argument would be http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2539#comment-38348 but I suspect that you realize that. Within the context of this question though, I'd still argue that Scheme and Common Lisp can be considered functional programming languages, which I probably wouldn't say of C.

Comment: Oh wow, return of the "Foo isn't functional" argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527753/. Count me out of this argument!

Comment: Agreed with Frank. Vijay, Greg, please take this argument to the Smalltalk threads. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PLT Racket has a web server- it's an up-to-date, actively developed Scheme offshoot, and may be something that you want to look into. Here's some documentation:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server-internal/index.html

There are a few StackOverflow threads that can provide some more answers to this:

[state of web development using functional programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230046/state-of-web-development-using-functional-programming-language)

[What are the popular 'web-ready' functional programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540145/what-are-the-popular-web-ready-functional-programming-languages/3540199)

Answer (score 5):

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) (and [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) not really a lisp) are also used for server side web development.

Answer (score 5):

- [BKNR](http://bknr.net/html/home.html), a Common Lisp web application environment
- [Hunchentoot](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/), a Common Lisp web server
- [Lisp-on-lines](http://www.cliki.net/lisp-on-lines), a Common Lisp web framework
- [Parenscript](http://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/), a Common Lisp -> Javascript translator
- [UnCommon Web](http://common-lisp.net/project/ucw/), a Common Lisp web framework

It's safe to say there's a fair bit of server side stuff going on for Common Lisp!

Update: In my newsfeed this evening, compliments of Xach: [A Common Lisp Web Development Primer, Part 1](http://redlinernotes.com/blog/?p=1232)

Answer (score 4):

Erlang is a functional language used (among other many things) for server side web development, e.g.

- http://www.erlang-web.org/,
- http://github.com/mochi/mochiweb,
- http://erlyweb.org/, ...

As for Common Lisp frameworks, see [Best web framework in Common-lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540953/best-web-framework-in-common-lisp)

Comment: What do you mean by "used to be"? Isn't it still used for that?

Comment: @NateC-K, yes of course, it is still used. Corrected misleading wording.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure is a very promising choice for server-side web development.

Key advantages:

- It's a **Lisp** (see Paul Graham's "[beating the averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html)" essay on why this is important)
- You get access to the full **Java ecosystem of libraries** - this is a huge advantage for server-side development (since the Java library ecosystem is second to none)
- It offers **high performance** - always compiled, takes full advantage of the JVM for optimisations etc. On the [benchmarks game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programs-are-fastest.html) it is the second fastest dynamically typed language (after Common Lisp)
- You can use **ClojureScript** (basically Clojure that compiles to JavaScript) on the client side for and end-to-end client server solution.

Currently the leading Clojure web framework is probably Noir (http://webnoir.org/) but there are various others starting to emerge.

Answer (score 3):

Hunchentoot is a nice webserver for CL. CL-WHO is an HTML generation library, and there is a mod_lisp for apache I think too. You can set up something with cl-fcgi, and have a server connect to it, like a CL-WHO + cl-fcgi setup, or cl-who + hunchentoot, or cl-who + mod_lisp. I'ts your choice.